# PROGRAMA EM C++ PULANDO INPUT

Tags: c++

Comecei a estudar C++ na faculdade e a professora pediu para fazer um pequeno script para cadastrar 3 pessoas e no fim imprimir a pessoa escolhida. Fiz o script com simples inputs e quando vou rodar ele só inicia o primeiro e pula todos os outros e mesmo no fim o resultado da variável Nome só pega a primeira letra digitada.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char nome1,nome2,nome3;

    char sexo1,sexo2,sexo3;

    int altura1,altura2,altura3;

    int cpf1,cpf2,cpf3;

    int peso1,peso2,peso3;

    cout<<"DIGITE O PRIMEIRO NOME: "<<endl;

    cin>>nome1;

    cout<<"DIGITE O CPF : "<<endl;

    cin>>cpf1;

    cout<<"DIGITE O SEXO [M/F] : "<<endl;

    cin>>sexo1;

    cout<<"DIGITE O PESO: "<<endl;

    cin>>peso1;

    cout<<"DIGITE A ALTURA EM CENTIMETROS : "<<endl;

    cin>>altura1;

    cout<<"QUAL PESSOA DESEJA MEDIR O IMC: "<<endl;

    cout<<"1 - "<<nome1<<" CPF - "<<cpf1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Utilize ```string``` no lugar de ```char``` na declaração das variáveis de nome.

Comment: Note também que você só trata nome1, cpf1, sexo1, peso1 e altura1. As demais variáveis, com sufixo 2 e 3, são declaradas mas ignoradas.

Answer (score 0):

O tipo primitivo `char` aceita apenas um caractere. Se digitar acima de um, o buffer de entrada aguarda o próximo `cin` e o alimenta com o próximo caractere. Recomendo utilizar o tipo de objeto `string` ou um array de characteres definido como `char[100] nome;`.